# Generating a web service in RSA 7.0 from Java file generates the commons-logging file

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis, rad

I have a Java class from which I generate a WSDL and other files using the Web service wizard. What's starting to happen now is when I try to generate a web service, somehow, in the lib folder, a commons-logging-1.0.4.jar file gets generated and after that I'm informed that I have two commons-logging jar in the classpath (which makes sense since I really have another in the EAR project). What can I try?

TLDR: When I try to generate a webservice from a Java file, it also generates commons logging then tells me I have another commons logging in the classpath - the one it generates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with the commons-logging jar, it was with an unrelated jar on the classpath which contained Log.java file. Renaming the jar helped the issue. Bottom line - I should have used Ctrl+Shift+T to track everything that contains the Log class.